# How to narrow types on an object T by passing an array of exclusions (keyof T)[]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I describe a type that can be used as a type guard to exclude keys from an object?

Below I have a function `getExcludedKeys` which filters out keys from the passed in object. 
What I am experiencing is that the type guard just does nothing and I get all 3 properties through, what I would like it to do is narrow the type down so that it excludes the filtered keys from the type.

I have used type guards in `filter` expressions before but never from a predefined array.

```
interface Foo {
  id: number
  val1: string
  val2: string
}

type KeysOf<T> = (keyof T)[]
const getKeys = <T> (obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as KeysOf<T>
const getExcludedKeys = <T> (obj: T, excludeKeys: KeysOf<T>) =>
  getKeys(obj)
    .filter((key): key is Exclude<keyof T, typeof excludeKeys> => { // This line isn't working as expected.
      return !excludeKeys.includes(key)
    })


const foo: Foo = {
  id: 1,
  val1: 'val1',
  val2: 'val2'
}

const result = getExcludedKeys(foo, ['val1', 'val2'])
  .map(key => key)  // EXPECTED :: key: "id"
                    // ACTUAL   :: key: "id" | "val1" | "val2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given an self-answer and then put a bounty on your question and added this comment to your answer:

> This all breaks if the array of excluded keys is defined in a variable/constant before being passed to exclude...

So I'm assuming that this is the problem you're concerned with. Indeed if I take your code, and do this, I get an error on the second argument of `exclude`:

```
const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"];
const b = exclude(a, toExclude)
    .map(key => {                   // (EXPECTED :: key: 'baz') (ACTUAL :: key: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz')
        if (key === 'bar') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'foo') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'baz') { }      // Okay
        if (key === 'yay') { }      // Okay
    });
```

Your issue is that when you declare a variable like this:

```
const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"];
```

**TypeScript will infer the "best common type" (this terminology is from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)). The "best common type" the type that fits the most common usage scenarios.** Generally when someone defines an array that contains string literals, the desired inferred type is `string[]`. This is similar to how when you do `const x = "moo";` the inferred type of `x` is `string` and not `"moo"`. If you want a narrower type for it, you need to be explicit `const x: "moo" = "moo"`. And similarly `const x = 1` will infer `number` for `x`, though it could have a narrower type.

For you, that's a problem because your array has to contain values which are a subset of the possible keys on the first argument you pass to `exclude`. **You have to tell TS that you mean the array to have a narrower type.** You could do it with:

```
const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"] as ["foo", "bar"];
```

If you have multiple arrays you need to type like this, it can get old to have to add type assertion every time. You could use a helper function to prevent from having to type out a type assertion each and every time. For instance:

```
function asKeysOfA<T extends (keyof typeof a)[]>(...values: T) { return values; }

const toExclude = asKeysOfA("foo", "bar");
```

`toExclude` above is inferred to have the type `["foo", "bar"]`. Here's a version that would work with any object type and not just `typeof a`:

```
function asKeysOf<O, T extends (keyof O)[]>(o: O, ...values: T) { return values; }

const toExclude = asKeysOf(a, "foo", "bar");
```

In this case you need to pass `a` as the first argument so that `T` can be properly inferred. `a` is not used by the function.

You may be wondering why, when you do `exclude(a, ["foo", "bar"])` you do not need to perform a type assertion because when inferring the type of the 2nd argument, TS uses a different method than the "best common type". It determines a "contextual type". If the structure can satisfy the type declared for the 2nd argument of `exclude`, then TS infers that type rather than a more general type and you don't have to use a type assertion.

This is actually what the `asKeysOfA` and `asKeysOf` functions above are exploiting: when the values are passed as parameters to these functions TS infer for them a contextual type, which then carries over when inferring the return values of the helper functions.

I'm going to add a complete example here derived from your code, which includes the helper functions that provide a good narrow tuple type for the variable `toExclude`. I did not see much benefit to the `KeysList`, and `Omit` type declarations. For me, they don't make the code easier to read. So I've removed them. The principle how of `exclude` is typed remains the same though.

```
function getAllKeys<T>(obj: T): (keyof T)[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];
}

function exclude<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, excludes: K) {
    return getAllKeys(obj)
        .filter((key: keyof T): key is Exclude<keyof T, K[number]> =>
                !excludes.includes(key));
}

const a = {
    foo: 'abc',
    bar: 'abc',
    baz: 'abc',
    yay: true
};

// function asKeysOfA<T extends (keyof typeof a)[]>(...values: T) { return values; }

// const toExclude = asKeysOfA("foo", "bar");

function asKeysOf<O, T extends (keyof O)[]>(o: O, ...values: T) { return values; }

const toExclude = asKeysOf(a, "foo", "bar");

const b = exclude(a, toExclude)
    .map(key => {                   // (EXPECTED :: key: 'baz') (ACTUAL :: key: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz')
        if (key === 'bar') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'foo') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'baz') { }      // Okay
        if (key === 'yay') { }      // Okay
    });
```

---

**TypeScript 3.4 is going to be released soon and provides some new functionality which affects what you're trying to do here.** In TypeScript 3.4 it is possible to ask the compiler to infer the narrowest possible type for literal values where it would otherwise infer the "best common type". You have to use the type assertion `as const`. So the `toExclude` array could be declared like this:

```
const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"] as const;
```

Note that this also make the array `readonly`. Consequently, the declaration of `exclude` should also expect a `readonly` array, so the definition of `K` must change to `K extends readonly ...`:

```
function exclude<T, K extends readonly (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, excludes: K) {
```

Here's an example:

```
function getAllKeys<T>(obj: T): (keyof T)[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];
}

function exclude<T, K extends readonly (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, excludes: K) {
    return getAllKeys(obj)
        .filter((key: keyof T): key is Exclude<keyof T, K[number]> =>
                !excludes.includes(key));
}

const a = {
    foo: 'abc',
    bar: 'abc',
    baz: 'abc',
    yay: true
};

const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"] as const;

const b = exclude(a, toExclude)
    .map(key => {                   // (EXPECTED :: key: 'baz') (ACTUAL :: key: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz')
      if (key === 'bar') { }      // Error
      if (key === 'foo') { }      // Error
      if (key === 'baz') { console.log("Q"); }      // Okay
      if (key === 'yay') {console.log("F"); }      // Okay
    });
```

This example behaves as expected with Typescript 3.4.0-rc

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to describe how type inference works, however, this doesn't solve my problem. I thought that there must have been a way to describe a type that would allow me to pass a pre-defined array of keys to `toExclude` without calling a function (asKeysOf) first, calling a function for the sake of inferring types doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: As I've shown before showing the utility functions, you can do it without a utility function by using a type assertion like `const toExclude = ["foo", "bar"] as ["foo", "bar"];`.  As for the rest, if I've inferred correctly the specific scenario you were facing,  then the only thing I can say is that due to limitations in TS, sometimes the only way to use type inference to get the result you want is to use a helper function.

Comment: TS 3.4 looks promising, thanks again for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of fiddeling I finally managed to crack it with a little help from @nucleartux with his Omit type.

All I needed was this wacky type `Omit<T, K extends KeysList<T>> = Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>` as a type guard in combination with `exclude` having a second generic type `K extends (keyof T)[]`

```
type KeysList<T> = (keyof T)[]
type Omit<T, K extends KeysList<T>> = Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>

function getAllKeys<T>(obj: T): KeysList<T> {
    return Object.keys(obj) as KeysList<T>
}

function exclude<T, K extends KeysList<T>>(obj: T, excludes: K) {
    const filterCallback = (key: keyof T): key is Omit<T, K> => // <-- THIS LINE
        !excludes.includes(key) 

    return getAllKeys(obj)
        .filter(filterCallback)
}

const a = {
    foo: 'abc',
    bar: 'abc',
    baz: 'abc',
    yay: true
};

const b = exclude(a, ['foo', 'bar'])
    .map(key => {                   // (EXPECTED :: key: 'baz') (ACTUAL :: key: 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz')
        if (key === 'bar') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'foo') { }      // Error
        if (key === 'baz') { }      // Okay
        if (key === 'yay') { }      // Okay
    });
```

Comment: This all breaks if the array of excluded keys is defined in a variable/constant before being passed to `exclude`...